# Prevent express-session from creating new sessions on multiple tab login causing CSRF token errors

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm running into a situation where a user will have multiple pages set to open on startup which is causing errors. I'm using express-session for session management and msal-node for authentication (with Authentication Code with PKCE flow). It all works when a user opens one tab, logs in, and can then open multiple tabs after that and the session cookie works as expected. However, it appears that on startup, both tabs make requests and are assigned different session IDs, causing both to initiate login with different OAuth parameters and clobber each other once the session cookie is set in the browser. I don't suppose there's an easy fix for this? Here's my relevant code:

```
app.use(session({
      name: process.env.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
      store: !!process.env.LOCAL_SESSION_STORE 
        ? new MemoryStore() 
        : await getRedisStore(session),
      secret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      rolling: true,
      cookie: {
        secure: process.env.ENV !== "local",
        httpOnly: true
        maxAge: SESSION_COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
      }
    }));
```

```
// this is based on code samples from msal-node for using state to secure redirecting back to the same endpoint that initiated the login
// NOTE: the CSRF token is what appears to get clobbered by having two requests.
router.post(REDIRECT_ENDPOINT, async function (req: Request, res, next) {
  logger.info(">> redirect");
  if (req.body.state) {
    const state = JSON.parse(cryptoProvider.base64Decode(req.body.state));

    logger.debug(`State: ${JSON.stringify(state)}`);
    logger.debug(`Session: ${JSON.stringify(req.session)}`);

    // check if csrfToken matches
    if (state.csrfToken === req.session.csrfToken) {
      req.session.authCodeRequest.code = req.body.code; // authZ code
      req.session.authCodeRequest.codeVerifier = req.session.pkceCodes.verifier; // PKCE Code Verifier

      try {
        const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenByCode(
          req.session.authCodeRequest
        );
        req.session.accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
        req.session.idToken = tokenResponse.idToken;
        req.session.account = tokenResponse.account;
        req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
        debug("Account: %s", JSON.stringify(tokenResponse.account));
        logger.info("<< redirect");
        res.redirect(state.redirectTo);
      } catch (error) {
        next(error);
      }
    } else {
      logger.error(`Tokens don't match!`);
      logger.error(JSON.stringify(state));
      logger.error(JSON.stringify(req.session));
      next(new Error("csrf token does not match"));
    }
  } else {
    next(new Error("state is missing"));
  }
```